# pymongo Collection initialize_unordered_bulk_op method broken

Tags: python, pymongo

TypeError("'Collection' object is not callable. If you meant to call the 'initialize_unordered_bulk_op' method on a 'Collection' object it is failing because no such method exists.")

Anyone else run into this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Ran into this problem in pymongo v4.0.  Release notes mention this, but it wasn't very obvious.

Changed in version 4.0: Removed the reindex, map_reduce, inline_map_reduce, parallel_scan, initialize_unordered_bulk_op, initialize_ordered_bulk_op, group, count, insert, save, update, remove, find_and_modify, and ensure_index methods.

Refer to [Migration Guide](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/migrate-to-pymongo4.html#pymongo4-migration-guide)